# binding mudblazor treeview to an object

Tags: c#, treeview, blazor, mudblazor

I am new to blazor and need to create a dynamic treeview where nodes can be created and deleted. All this data is saved in database. After pulling the data from database what kind of object I need to create to bind to Mudtreeview?
If only first level nodes are rendered initially, how can I load the children on node click?
is there any example somewhere? All the sample code on mudblazor site is with static data.

Comment: `StateHasChanged()` on node click maybe? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding and removeing items is easy if you bind the treeview to a collection in MudBlazor. I made a little demo for you to can play around online: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cuwlvFQcfJTzHuki

Here is the full code of the example:

```html
<MudButton OnClick="AddItems" Variant="Variant.Filled">Add items</MudButton>
<MudButton OnClick="DeleteItems" Variant="Variant.Filled">Delete items</MudButton>

<MudPaper Width="300px" Elevation="0">
    <MudTreeView Items="TreeItems" MultiSelection="true" @bind-ActivatedValue="ActivatedValue" @bind-SelectedValues="SelectedValues">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@context.IsExpanded" Items="@context.TreeItems" Value="@context"
                             Icon="@context.Icon" Text="@context.Title" EndText="@context.Number?.ToString()" EndTextTypo="@Typo.caption" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </MudTreeView>
</MudPaper>

<div style="width: 100%">
    <MudText Typo="@Typo.subtitle1">Activated item: @(ActivatedValue?.Title)</MudText>
    <MudText Typo="@Typo.subtitle1">Sum of selected items: @GetSelectedSum()</MudText>
</div>

@code {
    private TreeItemData ActivatedValue { get; set; }

    private HashSet<TreeItemData> SelectedValues { get; set; }

    private HashSet<TreeItemData> TreeItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<TreeItemData>();

    public class TreeItemData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public int? Number { get; set; }

        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }

        public HashSet<TreeItemData> TreeItems { get; set; }

        public TreeItemData(string title, string icon, int? number = null)
        {
            Title = title;
            Icon = icon;
            Number = number;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object x) {
            var other = x as TreeItemData;
            if (other==null)
                return false;
            return other.Title==Title;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return Title.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("All Mail", Icons.Filled.Email));
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("Trash", Icons.Filled.Delete));
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("Categories", Icons.Filled.Label)
        {
            IsExpanded = true,
            TreeItems = new HashSet<TreeItemData>()
            {
                new TreeItemData("Social", Icons.Filled.Group, 90),
                new TreeItemData("Updates", Icons.Filled.Info, 2294),
                new TreeItemData("Forums", Icons.Filled.QuestionAnswer, 3566),
                new TreeItemData("Promotions", Icons.Filled.LocalOffer, 733)
            }
        });
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("History", Icons.Filled.Label));
    }

    public int GetSelectedSum()
    {
        return SelectedValues?.Sum(i => i.Number ?? 0) ?? 0;
    }

    private int i=0;

    public void AddItems() {
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("Added Item " + (i++), Icons.Filled.Coronavirus));
    }

    public void DeleteItems() {
        var item=TreeItems.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Title.StartsWith("Added Item"));
        TreeItems.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Let me go through this.

Comment: By adding System.Linq namespace, I was able to get firstOrDefault