# MudBlazor context menu in treeview or nested list

Tags: c#, blazor, treeview, mudblazor

I'm trying to make a tree view with mudblazor. The tree consists of different nested objects. Furthermore, every item needs a context menu (or any other button) to add a child item / edit item / delete item.

I found this [binding-mudblazor-treeview-to-an-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184254/binding-mudblazor-treeview-to-an-object), but this is about the same object that is nested inside itself (TreeViewItem with List of TreeViewItem). I need to nest different objects (e.g. Orders with List of Products).

This code works, but any attempt at adding a context menu to the orders seems to fail:

```
<MudTreeView T="string">
    @foreach (var order in OrderList)
    {
        <MudTreeViewItem Value="@order.Name">
                @foreach (var product in order.Products)
                {
                    <MudTreeViewItem Value="@product.Name">
                        <Content>
                            <MudMenu Dense AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomLeft" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopLeft" ActivationEvent="@MouseEvent.RightClick">
                                <ActivatorContent>
                                    <MudText>@product.Name</MudText>
                                </ActivatorContent>
                                <ChildContent>
                                    <MudMenuItem OnClick="@(() => Delete(product))">Delete</MudMenuItem>
                                </ChildContent>
                            </MudMenu>
                        </Content>
                    </MudTreeViewItem>
                }
        </MudTreeViewItem>
    }
</MudTreeView>
```

Then I tried it with MudList, but I got the same result there. I can get a context menu on the inner items, but not the outer items:

```
    <MudList>
        @foreach (var order in OrderList)
        {
            <MudListItem Text="@order.Name">
                <NestedList>
                    @foreach (var product in order.Products)
                    {
                        <MudListItem Value="@product.Name">
                            <MudMenu Dense AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomLeft" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopLeft" ActivationEvent="@MouseEvent.RightClick">
                                <ActivatorContent>
                                    <MudText>@product.Name</MudText>
                                </ActivatorContent>
                                <ChildContent>
                                    <MudMenuItem OnClick="@(() => Delete(product))">Delete</MudMenuItem>
                                </ChildContent>
                            </MudMenu>
                        </MudListItem>
                    }
                </NestedList>
            </MudListItem>
        }
    </MudList>
```

I also tried just add a button next to the item name instead of a context menu, but then the nested items are displayed next to each other, instead of under each other.

```
<MudTreeView T="string">
        @foreach (var order in OrderList)
        {
            <MudTreeViewItem Value="@order.Name">
                <Content>
                    <MudText>@order.Name</MudText>
                    @foreach (var product in order.Products)
                    {
                        <MudTreeViewItem Value="@product.Name">
                            <Content>
                                <MudText>@product.Name</MudText>
                                <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Add" Size="Size.Small" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="@(() => Delete(product))" />
                            </Content>
                        </MudTreeViewItem>
                    }
                    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Add" Size="Size.Small" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="@(() => AddProduct(order))" />
                </Content>
            </MudTreeViewItem>
        }
    </MudTreeView>
```

Any help to get some kind of treeview with some kind of add/edit buttons for each item is appreciated!